# In CakePHP, is there a way to access the Grandparent of a model in the belongsTo relationship?

Tags: php, cakephp

```
Line belongsTo Cart
Cart belongsTo Vendor

Vendor hasMany Carts
Cart hasMany Lines
```

I'm trying to access the Vendor name of a particular Line in CakePhP, which, as indicated above, is a child of the Carts model, and a grandchild of the Vendors model.

I can get the vendor ID from `$this->Part['Cart']['vendor_id']` but from there I have no access to the Vendor model. I'm trying to avoid building a custom query because I'll need to do this same thing in several models.

I would like to use `$this->AppModel->read()` or something to set the Vendor data as part of the Cart model just like the Cart data is part of the Part model.

Or do I need to do something with the belongsTo part of the AppModel?

Comment: for getting granparent
$this->line->recursive=2;
$this->Line->find();

Comment: Thanks, works great! Please put your comment in an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: Just a side note: Use Containable behavior. It's more intuitive than recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting granparent you need to tell how deep your association is...In your case it is 2.

By default it is 1.

```
$this->line->recursive=2; $this->Line->find();
```